# Can depends_on in terraform be set to a file path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, iaas, aws-config

I am trying to break down my **main.tf** file . So I have set aws config via terraform, created the configuration recorder and set the delivery channel to a s3 bucket created in the same main.tf file. Now for the AWS config rules, I have created a separate file viz **config-rule.tf**. As known , every aws_config_config_rule that we create has a **depends_on** clause where in we call the dependent resource, which in this case being **aws_config_configuration_recorder**. So my question is can I interpolate the depends_on clause to something like :

```
    resource "aws_config_config_rule" "s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_enabled" {
    name = "s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_enabled"

    source {
    owner             = "AWS"
    source_identifier = "S3_BUCKET_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED"
    }

    depends_on = ["${file("aws-config-setup.tf")}"]
    }
```

Considering I move my aws config setup from my main.tf file to a new file called **aws-config-setup.tf**.

Comment: Why not have it depend on a resource instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you shouldn't need to make any changes for this to work, assuming you didn't move code to its own module (a separate directory).

When terraform executes in a particular directory it takes all files into account, basically treating them all as one terraform file.

So, in general, if you had a `main.tf` that looks like the following

```
resource "some_resource" "resource_1" {
  # ...
}

resource "some_resource" "resource_2" {
  # ...

  depends_on = [some_resource.resource_1]
}
```

and you decided to split these out into the following files

**file1.tf**

```
resource "some_resource" "resource_1" {
  # ...
}
```

**file2.tf**

```
resource "some_resource" "resource_2" {
  # ...

  depends_on = [some_resource.resource_1]
}
```

if `terraform` is run in the same directory, it will evaluate the `main.tf` scenario exactly the same as the multi-file scenario.